# How to open ionic 4 modal via routes?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I need to open modal vis routes.

I've tried like this, but it hasn't worked

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.presentModal();
  }

  async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AuthPasswordRecoveryPage,
      componentProps: { }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

Comment: its working perfectly. are you implementing your component with ngOnInit?? or any error in console??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this promise chain within your function instead of async await:

```
presentModal() {    
this.modalController
 .create({
   component: AuthPasswordRecoveryPage,
   componentProps: { }
 })
 .then(modalEl => {
   modalEl.present();
 })
}
```